# Size of a website backup increased 3 times when downloaded

Tags: web, cpanel, database-backups

I downloaded my site's backup from the file manager, where the size was 4.67GB, but when it downloaded, the size is has increased 3 folds to 13.92GB.

Is it normal or shall I start a fresh download again?

[image: When Downloaded]

[image: Size in Cpanel/Filemanager]

Answer (score 0):

Your downloaded file is in .tar format where as the backup file generated on the server is in tar.gz format.
tar.gz is the compressed form and hence of less size. In case you are using mac, the system has default setting to uncompress upon download competition.

You may extract tar.gz to tar on the server level to verify the size.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, helped a lot in comprehending.

Is there a way to highly compress it again on Mac in order to save space?

Comment: Yes, you can compress on mac too. Either you can simply right click on the file and select compress which will make .zip of the tar file of yours. For tar.gz, you can use command line and run the command : tar -cvzf filename.tar.gz filename